# Should there be a tag for MSRPC?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should there be a tag for Microsoft Remote Procedure Call or does the DCE tag suffice for people? I was running a search and can find nothing on Stack Overflow or Super User Stack Exchange sites. What are people's opinions on the issue?

Comment: I don't think its necessary to have a tag for ever protocol that exists.

Comment: You think there would be too many? I was considering the possibility of running a client-server configuration (of sorts) using the protocol. I take it you are suggesting you think there is not sufficient demand to discuss the protocol, or that the DCE tag covers it???

Comment: I replied without checking to see, if the tag didn't exist, Superuser already has a tag for this [protocol](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/RPC).  I stand by my comment though, not ever protocol needs its own tag, its not always appropriate.  Superuser does not have a tag for `DCE`.  Can't speak to anything with regards to that.

Comment: Really? Strange it didn't come up when I searched. What's the exact search string? I was using [MSRPC].

Comment: Hhhhhmmmmmmm, upon further inspection the DCE tag does seem to be in Stack Overflow rather Super User which seems counter-intuitive to me. Do you know what the rationale is for including it in SO but not SU?

Comment: I don't involve myself in SO community, because of the abusive community filled with vindictive people, because of a comment I make at Superuser.  In other words, vindictive people with reputation at SO, downvoted my questions there because they couldn't do it here.  If you want to know about a tag for SO ask at their meta website, we have no say, in what tags they have.

Comment: anyone with >2k rep can create tags, there isn't a rationale or decision process behind creating tags. Probably felt it wasn't necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the tag wiki excerpts from Stack Overflow:

dce:

> The Distributed Computing Environment (DCE) is a framework and toolkit
>   for developing client/server applications, developed in the early 1990s.

rpc:

> Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is an approach
>   to interprocessor or distributed communication
>   wherein a set of services or procedures are exposed to remote clients. 
>   RPC is both a general concept for interprocessor communication
>   and shorthand for Sun's original implementation …

It seems to me that the "dce" tag is relevant only to developers,
and, as such, belongs only on Stack Overflow. 
The "rpc" tag is a bit of an edge case —
the RPC protocol *per se* is pretty much off-topic at Super User,
but there seem to be just barely enough questions
about manifestations of RPC at the user level
to justify having such a tag here. 
I don't see any reason to delve into individual vendors' versions
of a programming tool — notice that Super User doesn't have a "sunrpc" tag,
either (while Stack Overflow does).

If you're talking about the possibility of ***developing***
a client-server configuration using MSRPC,
your question(s) probably belong on Stack Overflow,
and you should try to get the tag created there. 
If you're talking about using a product that uses the protocol,
it seems unlikely that your questions (if on-topic for Super User)
would need to be tagged to that level of specificity.